# Muffin sticks to paper cases

Tags: non-stick, muffins

Today I tried to cook my favourite Raspberry and White Chocolate muffins using a recipe I found on BBC Good Food.

However after cooking them for the set amount of time and removing them from the muffin tray I found that when I tried to peel away the paper cases (from the muffin) the muffin stuck to the case.

The mixture itself was cooked but for some reason it stuck to the paper cases, this is also odd because I've done this recipe before and it worked fine. I've tried to think of any factors that may have changed when cooking for a second time and all I can think of are:

- The raspberries were cut slightly larger (in half rather than in quarters/thirds)
- Slightly less egg whites were used (because of a slight spill)

Could these factors have caused the muffin to stick to it's paper case?

Comment: were very ripe raspberries?? you always used the same oven?

Comment: Raspberries we equally ripe. Although the oven I used was different , the first time I used a gas oven and the second time I used a electric fan oven.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't left them to cool long enough. After I left them for about 2-3 hours and tried again to peel the case off, it came off perfectly and nothing stuck to it.

Sorry about the false alarm but I never thought that not leaving them to cool long enough would have caused this kind of problem.

Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try coating the raspberries in cornstarch prior to baking the mixture and the slight egg spill may have a little to do with it.  Baking is a precise practice and even the smallest miscalculation can change the end product you are hoping for.

Comment: or spray the case with a non stick spray.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess its the fact that the two batches were in different ovens.

Convection (the one with the fan blowing air) and non-convection ovens can cook fairly differently (especially if you had convection turned on). You will probably need a lower temperature in a convection oven (with convection on).

Also, ovens often aren't temperature-calibrated very well, and two different ovens may be 50°F/25°C different when set to the same temperature. Gas ovens are also often subject to greater temperature swings as the gas burner's heat is instant.

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem was you added too much raspberry into your muffin and not enough egg white which neutralizes that effect.

Comment: Hmm. When you say 'neutralizes that effect', what is 'that effect'?